# Emails sending with the wrong name on Outlook 2011 Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

Our client has 6 Macs. We recently set up Outlook 2011 with an exchange account for all of the users.

On one of the Macs, I had setup the profile for another user (Person B), before removing it and adding the correct person (Person A).

Now what is happening, is when Person A sends an email to anyone, the recipient receives an email from Person A's email address, but with the name of Person B. Like this:

```
Person B <Person.A@domain.com>
```

I can see in the address book, that Person B is indeed next to the email address of Person A, We've removed this several times but it comes back.

Does anyone know why this keeps happening?

Comment: Just to add, this also happened to another Mac, but that problem seems to have not come back,.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to remove all of the user accounts and recreate them.